# Java sparkSQL - Problem with Dataset lookups

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

have been struggling to get this sorted
I have Dataset#1 personInfo

```
---------------------------
|field_1 |field_2|field_3|...
-----------------
|personID|  DoB  |intAge |...
```

---

DataSet#2 ageCodes

```
-----------------
|field_1|field_2|
-----------------
|  age  |ageCode|
-----------------
|  35   |  6    |
-----------------
|  36   |  6    |
-----------------
|  37   |  6    |
-----------------
|  38   |  7    |
-----------------
|  39   |  7    |
-----------------
|  40   |  7    |
-----------------
```

Am trying to update `personInfo` row with their `ageCode`

```
personInfo = personInfo.withColumn("ageCode", 
  ageCodes.filter(col("age").equalTo(personInfo.col("intAge"))).col("ageCode")
);
```

have tried several variations of the above & can't seem to get it quite right

any help gratefully received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use join:

```java
personInfo = personInfo.join(ageCodes, ageCodes.col("age").equalTo(personInfo.col("intAge")), "left").drop("age");
```